# Error installing cookbook with Vagrant and librarian-chef-nochef plugin

Tags: windows, chef-infra, vagrant, librarian

I'm using Vagrant with [librarian-chef-nochef](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef) plugin on Windows host. It works fine until I add a cookbook with "git" option to my Cheffile. Like this:

```
# Cheffile
site "http://community.opscode.com/api/v1"

cookbook "apt"
cookbook "nginx"
cookbook "nodejs", :github => "redguide/nodejs"
```

Then I get a strange error about missing README.md file:

```
C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.1.0/lib/librarian/chef/metadata.rb:15:in `instance_eval': No such file or directory - ./README.md (Errno::ENOENT)
```

My configuration:

- Windows 7 x64
- Vagrant 1.5.4 with librarian-chef-nochef plugin

Here is the full report:

```
> vagrant provision
==> default: Installing Chef cookbooks with Librarian-Chef...
C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.1.0/lib/librarian/chef/metadata.rb:15:in `instance_eval': No such file or directory - ./README.md (Errno::ENOENT)
        from (eval):6:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.1.0/lib/librarian/chef/metadata.rb:15:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.1.0/lib/librarian/chef/metadata.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.1.0/lib/librarian/chef/manifest_reader.rb:28:in `new'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.1.0/lib/librarian/chef/manifest_reader.rb:28:in `compile_manifest'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.1.0/lib/librarian/chef/manifest_reader.rb:23:in `read_manifest'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.1.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/local.rb:57:in `fetch_manifest_data'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.1.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/local.rb:49:in `manifest_data'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.1.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/local.rb:28:in `fetch_version'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:121:in `fetch_version!'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:113:in `fetched_version'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:59:in `version'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:97:in `satisfies?'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/dependency.rb:121:in `satisfied_by?'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:103:in `block in check_manifest'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:104:in `each'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:104:in `find'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:104:in `check_manifest'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:63:in `block inrecursive_resolve'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:70:in `block inrecursive_resolve'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:70:in `block inrecursive_resolve'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:50:in `resolve'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver.rb:23:in `resolve'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/action/resolve.rb:26:in `run'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef-0.1.1/lib/vagrant-librarian-chef/action/librarian_chef.rb:24:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-cachier-0.7.1/lib/vagrant-cachier/action/configure_bucket_root.rb:20:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'

        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'

        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'

        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:157:in `action'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/plugins/commands/provision/command.rb:35:in `block in execute'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:200:in `block in with_target_vms'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:194:in `each'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:194:in `with_target_vms'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/plugins/commands/provision/command.rb:34:in `execute'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:248:in `cli'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.4/bin/vagrant:164:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed in next version of *vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef* plugin (0.1.2)

Answer (score 1):

if the metadata.rb file require readme file (long_description IO.read(File.join(File.dirname(**FILE**), 'README.md')) some thing like this) you can create a readme file in the same directory with metadata with something as file content

Comment: I tried to create a README.md file in plugin's directory next to the metadata.rb. But it didn't work.

Comment: you should create README file in this path (C:/Users/silentvick/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.1.0/lib/librarian/chef/README.md)

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly where I created it. Didn't help.

Comment: Yes, I do. For example, `git`, `nginx`, `php`, `composer`, they all work fine.

Comment: Please stop doing the IO.read on the README for the "long description" of a cookbook which you got problem when installed. It should be a semantic description of the cookbook contained in the metadata. I realize this is the default value when constructing a new cookbook, but it's not the best way to describe your cookbook, especially with all the markdown formatting and such.

Comment: I'm not the author of cookbook. I'm just trying to install cookbook from github.

Comment: but you can custom cookbook by yourself